# How to use special characters & | and ⊕ in the Split() method?

Tags: java, special-characters, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I tried

```
String text = "1&2⊕3|4";
String[] s = text.split("|⊕&");
```

And nothing happened, I also tried

```
String text = "1&2⊕3|4";
String[] s = text.split("\\|\\⊕\\&");
```

And nothing happened. So, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a *character class* by adding brackets:

```
String text = "1&2⊕3|4";
String[] s = text.split("[|⊕&]");
```

You can read more about character classes in [this excellent tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 1):

`split` uses [Regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

You are splitting on the `String` "|⊕&". You need to `split` on a [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
String[] s = text.split("[|⊕&]");
```

Whilst you need to escape the special characters `|` and `&` in Regex, if they are inside a character class then you do not. In fact only the closing bracket, `]`,  and backslash needs to be escaped in a character class (strictly speaking `-` needs to be escaped, but not if it either starts of ends the class).